# How can I implement internationalization (i18n) for my website using node.js+express.js

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I'm kind of new to node.js +express currently am practicing on a website and I want to make it support multiple languages through internationalization (i18n). I'm looking for guidance on implementing i18n clearly and straightforwardly.

- **am using node.js+express.js**

I would appreciate it if someone could provide a step-by-step guide or point me to relevant resources that explain how to set up internationalization for a web project. I'm particularly interested in the following aspects:

1. Handling translations for different languages.
2. Switching between languages dynamically.
3. Any best practices or tips for a smooth i18n implementation.

If you have experience with i18n, please share your insights. Code examples or references to well-documented tutorials would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll guide you through the process with code examples and references to help you set up i18n in your project.

First, you'll need to install the required packages. For i18n in Express.js, commonly used packages are **i18n** and **i18next**. Install them using npm:

```js
npm install i18n i18next
```

In your Express.js application, set up the i18n middleware. This middleware will handle language detection and loading translations.

```js
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')
const { I18n } = require('i18n')

const i18n = new I18n({
  locales: ['en', 'es'], // you can add more languages as needed
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'locales')
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  cookie: 'lang',
  objectNotation: true,
})

const app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  i18n.init(req, res)
  res.end(res.__('Hello'))
})

// This is to handle missing translations to avoid displaying keys
// check for more details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n

i18n.configure({
  defaultNS: 'common', // Use a common namespace for translations
  fallbackNS: 'common',
  missingKeyHandler: function (locale, namespace, key, res) {
    console.warn(`Missing translation: ${key} for ${locale}`);
    return key;
  },
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Create a locales directory in your project to store translation files for each language. Let say for example, create locales/en.json and locales/es.json with translations.

```js
// en.json
{
  "greeting": "Hello, World!",
  "welcome": "Welcome to our website."
}

// es.json
{
  "greeting": "¡Hola, Mundo!",
  "welcome": "Bienvenido a nuestro sitio web."
}
```

Now you can create a route or a middleware to handle language switching. For example:

```js
app.get('/switch/:lang', (req, res) => {
  const { lang } = req.params;
  res.cookie('lang', lang); // save language cookie 
  res.redirect('back'); // Redirect back to the previous page
});
```

In your views, use the "__" function provided by i18n to display translated text. I'll be using EJS Templating engine

```html
<!-- Example using EJS template engine -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= i18n.getLocale() %>">
<head>
  <title><%= __('welcome') %></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><%= __('greeting') %></h1>
  <p><%= __('welcome') %></p>
  <a href="/switch/en">English</a> | <a href="/switch/es">Español</a>
</body>
</html>
```

These steps should help you get started with implementing internationalization in your Node.js and Express.js web application. I hope this help you

Comment: thank you man this was so helpful to me. thank you i will go through the steps

Comment: Alright, I'm happy it helped you.